# HTML 5 Doctype causing quirksmode?

Tags: html, doctype

Does using an HTML 5 Doctype cause Quirks mode in modern browsers, since HTML5 isn't out yet?

(That is Modern Browsers were out before HMTL5 started spreading, so they don't properly support it.)

If yes, does this mean that the HTML 5 Doctype is tentatively like none at all?

EDIT: If not, what *does* it do in browsers that don't support  and the like?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No it doesn't, see this [article](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-doctype/).

> What's nice about this new DOCTYPE, especially, is that all current browsers (IE, FF, Opera, Safari) will look at it and switch the content into standards mode - even though they don't implement HTML5. This means that you could start writing your web pages using HTML5 today and have them last for a very, very, long time.

Comment: Thanks. Good link - I ended reading through the HTML5 spec...
Informative indeed.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help

Answer (score 11):

According to [Wikipedia table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Comparison_of_document_types) (that I love) HTML 5 DOCTYPE triggers **full standard mode** for:

**FF, Chrome, Opera 7.5+, Safari, Konqeror 3.5+ and also IE8**!!!

and triggers **Almost standard mode** [*] for:

**IE6 and IE7**

So it's definitely the best DOCTYPE ever created!

*"One DOCTYPE to bring them all and in the darkness bind them..." [Lords of the rings]*

[*] "Almost standards" does NOT make such a big difference to full standard mode, in the same Wikipedia link above you can find more details.

Answer (score 3):

No it does not.

Comment: What does it do then in older browsers?

Comment: It has exactly the same effect in all browsers as using the HTML 4.01 strict doctype (among others).